# How do you split code into multiple files when using a module that is required for all files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

In this case I'm using puppeteer chrome headless browser and MongoDB. Here's my code:

```js
var browser = await puppeteer.launch()
var page = await browser.newPage()
var db = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bot")
var scraped_users = db.collection("scraped_users")
```

I want to split my code into relevant files like `chrome.js`, `twitter.js`, `database,js`, `utilities.js`, etc. Problem is I need those 4 variables I declared above in pretty much every file and it seems stupid to pass them in every function. I also can't re-declare them into every file because that would open a new chrome browser and establish a new database connection.

Comment: Are you using a module system?

Comment: Your using node, so node has a module system built in.  So basically create a new js file say called global.  that then module.exports   browser, page & db.

Comment: @Keith but if I do that and require('./global.js') in 5 files, it's gonna open 5 browser windows, no?

Comment: No.. if you require a file, it doesn't execute it again.  Because your also using async, inside your global.js, I would create a function call init, this then can be async.  So when you start you app, you can do await global.init(), and then everywhere else just do, global.browser, global.page etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a file `init.js`:

```
/*let isInitialized, browser, page, db, scraped_users

async function init() {
    if (!isInitialized) {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    db = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bot")
    scraped_users = db.collection("scraped_users")
    isInitialized = true
    }
    return { browser, page, db, scraped_users }
}

module.exports = init*/

let common = {}; //store some global's.

//this should only be called once, eg. when App starts
common.init = async function () {
    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    this.page = await this.browser.newPage()
    this.db = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bot")
    this.scraped_users = this.db.collection("scraped_users")
}

module.exports = common;
```

then use it like:

```
/*const init = require('./init.js')

init().then(({browser, page, db, scraped_users}) => {
    console.log(browser, page, db, scraped_users)
})*/

const common = require('./common');
const doSomething = require('./do-something');

async function run() {
    await common.init(); //this only needs to be done once
    console.log(common.browser); //etc
    await doSomething();
}

//now inside other units, eg. do-something.js
const common = require('./common');
async function doSomething() {
    console.log(common.browser); 
}
```

Comment: Your nearly there,.. you can't use await inside the init of a module, module loading in node is not async.  but create a function called `async init()` and export that.

Comment: @Keith - true, edited. Feel free to suggest or critic on anything else (since I'm new to node myself)

Comment: Ok, no problem.. I'll just do a quick edit of yours to show the changes.  Be a bit easier. It's not far off.. :)

Comment: Done, I've left your original code as comments to show the difference.

Comment: Thanks - Idd this looks better - clean js way